# Is there a way to limit the characters that are matched in a regular expression without limiting what is captured

Tags: regex

What I'm trying to achieve
Given the three strings below, I am trying to match the Y tf toward the beginning of each string.

```
15 YstfAWIN25  desired matches ->  Y tf
15 YstfMSIN25  desired matches ->  Y tf
15 Ystf20IN25  desired matches ->  Y tf
```

This regular expression ([ftY]) meets my objectives, however, it is too brittle and would yield erroneous results with minor changes to the string. For example, 15 YstfMYIN25 would result in the following match **Y tf Y**  - *I don't want to match that second Y*.

As a result, I tried using a non-capture group to limit the characters that would be matched.

```
([ftY])(?:AW|MS|\d+)
```

This regular expression yields the following match when a second Y (15 YstfMYIN25) is included in the full string:

```
15 YstfMYIN25  desired matches ->  f
```

The addition of the capture group made expression skip over the Y and t.  I did play around with making the capture group greedy and the non-capture group lazy, but I got the same result. Is there a way to use a non-capture group (or otherwise) to limit the characters that can be captured and still capture all the characters of interest?  In this exmaple Y ft only.

I have some examples below:

https://regex101.com/r/EDPqsl/1
https://regex101.com/r/R1tiXz/1

Comment: You're matching the `f, t, or Y` right before `AW` or `MS`. What is the actual criteria for which letter it should match?

Comment: Try capturing these into 3 groups: `^.*?([ftY]).*?(?!\1)([ftY]).*?(?!\1|\2)([ftY])`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nharlg/1).

Comment: Please edit to state your question in words. Examples are useful for illustration but questions expressed in terms of examples alone are rarely clear and complete, and this one is not an exception.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Thanks for the reply  Wiktor.  It seems the negative lookahead is what I needed. If you would like to turn your comment into an answer you will certainly get the checkmark.  Thanks again.

Comment: @barmar - I want to match all three letters f, t, and Y, but not the s or anything else.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^.*?([ftY]).*?(?!\1)([ftY]).*?(?!\1|\2)([ftY])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nharlg/1). The three letters will land into three separate capturing groups.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `([ftY])` - Group 1: `f`, `t` or `Y`
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?!\1)([ftY])` - Group 2: `f`, `t` or `Y`, but not the value captured in Group 1
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?!\1|\2)([ftY])` - Group 3: `f`, `t` or `Y`, but not the value captured in Groups 1 and 2.